# Select on Mysql inverse order

Tags: php, mysql

i have a MySql table that consists of 2 basic things:
The id and a value.
To show that on my page, i need to select, for example, the last 100 rows on reversed order.
So imagine that someone is putting data on it:

```
Id, value
1, 10
2, 9
3, 21
4, 15
```

i need, to select the last "3" rows (LIMIT + ORDER Clause), but not like this: 4,3,2 but like this: 2,3,4.

I know how to do that on code, but maybe there is a simple solution for that on Mysql and i don`t know.
Thanks

My SQL Query is like this right now:

```
SELECT `Data`.`id`, `Data`.`log_id`, `Data`.`value`, `Data`.`created` FROM `control_panel`.`datas` AS `Data` WHERE `Data`.`id` > 1000 AND `Data`.`log_id` = (2) ORDER BY `Data`.`id` DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: a LIMIT clause will do what i don`t want to do... get in reverse order

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp <--- SELECT OrderPrice FROM Orders ORDER BY O_Id DESC LIMIT 3 ---- the order by DESC will tell it not to be in reverse

Comment: limit has nothing to do with order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the first `ORDER BY` in a subselect which will return a limited selection ordered in descending order, then you can order that result in the outer query in ascending order:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT id, value
        FROM tbl
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 3
    ) a
ORDER BY
   a.id
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be with a sub-select.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) tmp
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: But i will get the rows in reversed order... how to reverse it on Mysql? or it`s not possible

Comment: `ORDER BY` can give you `ASC` or `DESC`

Comment: The correct is to use DESC, but then i would get this id`s order: 4,3,2 instead of 2,3,4

Comment: @IvanSeidel, to get 2,3,4 back, may be you could do a sorting again, if that really matters.

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
 SELECT t.*
 (SELECT * FROM table_name 
      ORDER BY column_name DESC 
      LIMIT 0,3) t
 ORDER BY t.column_name ASC
```

use `DESC` to descending order, `ASC` to increasing order